# ScrollViewer Always Visible under Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I have a ScrollViewer which works perfectly (per Auto setting) on Vista but when placed onto a Windows 7 machine the scrollbars are always visible. Currently set to Auto - the desired default.

I need to have them set to Auto so if the windows is re-sized smaller, the user can use the scrollbar to navigate.

Ideas on why Windows 7 is treating the ScrollViewer control is behaving in this way?

Thanks - Glenn

```
<Window
    x:Name="_MyPanel"
    Width="2560"
    Height="1427"
    MaxWidth="2560"
    MaxHeight="1427"
    MinWidth="510"
    MinHeight="510"
    WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
    Left="0"
    Top="136">

<ScrollViewer
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto"
        Background="{StaticResource Black}"
        CanContentScroll="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
</ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

Comment: I tried your code and works fine on my Windows7 box. Have you tried compiling the code on a Windows7 machine? Don't think it matters, but is worth a shot.

Comment: Are the DPI settings the same across both machines?